# Trinidad 1.2.3 can't running in windows server 2008 R2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, trinidad-gem

I have an rails app was using trinidad 1.0.5 on windows server 2008 R2, but today I update trinidad to 1.2.3, and find out it unsupported. Is trinidad no more support windows platform?

the message when I run trinidad:

```
c:\myapp> jruby -S trinidad -e production
Error daemonizing Trinidad: Unsupported Operating System Windows Server 2008 R2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support has not been dropped for the Windows platform, but you have probably run up against a bug.

**Are you using 64-bit Server 2008 R2?**

There is an open issue on the [Trinidad Init Services](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad_init_services) GitHub page for 64-bit 2008 R2 entitled "[The bundled version of prunsrv doesn't work on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit](https://github.com/trinidad/trinidad_init_services/issues/3)"

Essentially, it is looking like the bundled library is 32-bit.

A workaround would be to download the 64-bit library linked from the issue and manually swap the library in-place, until Trinidad has been scripted to do this for you.